# Using moment.js to convert date to string "MM/dd/yyyy"

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I need to take the date value from jquery datepicker turn it into string format "MM/dd/yyyy" so it can do the right ajax post. When the page loads or upon changing the datepicker, a jquery ajax call is made.

I have this code:

```
var sTimestamp =
moment($("#start_ts").datepicker("getDate")).format("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

But it doesn't turn it into "MM/dd/yyyy". When I use fiddler to check what is sent down the wire, this is the body:

```
startTimestamp=03%2FTh%2Fyyyy&endTimestamp=03%2FTh%2Fyyyy&pageSize=50&pageNum=0
```

If I use the compose in fiddler and change the body to:

```
startTimestamp=03/13/2013&endTimestamp=03/14/2013&pageSize=50&pageNum=0
```

I get the right response. So, my question is, is there a way to take a date object and format it to a string "MM/dd/yyyy" using moment.js? Or is there something wrong with the way I get the date from datepicker?

Btw, I am assuming that datepicker.getDate returns a date object since that's what the jQuery docs tell me.

Thank you,

Answer (score 90, accepted):

I think you just have incorrect casing in the format string. According to the documentation this should work for you: `MM/DD/YYYY`

[moment.js documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

Answer (score 167):

```
StartDate = moment(StartDate).format('MM-YYYY');
```

...and MySQL date format:

```
StartDate = moment(StartDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Comment: MySQL date format (YYYY-MM-DD) is also alphanumerically sortable, it can be used in filenames to sort files, its clear and humanly readable (not confusing like dd/mm and mm/dd is), ISO 8601 and pretty much the only sane format. "01/02/2016" is just ... "What? Where are you from? What date format do they use there?" ;)

Comment: Now your `StartDate` has the datatype `Moment` instead of `string` after formatting.

Answer (score 16):

Use:

> date.format("MM/DD/YYYY") or date.format("MM-DD-YYYY")}

Other Supported formats for reference:

### Months:

> **M** 1 2 ... 11 12
>
> **Mo**    1st 2nd ... 11th 12th
>
> **MM**    01 02 ... 11 12
>
> **MMM**   Jan Feb ... Nov Dec
>
> **MMMM**  January February ... November December

### Day:

> **d** 0 1 ... 5 6
>
> **do**    0th 1st ... 5th 6th
>
> **dd**    Su Mo ... Fr Sa
>
> **ddd**   Sun Mon ... Fri Sat
>
> **dddd**  Sunday Monday ... Friday Saturday

### Year:

> **YY**    70 71 ... 29 30
>
> **YYYY**  1970 1971 ... 2029 2030
>
> **Y** 1970 1971 ... 9999 +10000 +10001

Answer (score 14):

```
.format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss')
```

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
var momentObj = $("#start_ts").datepicker("getDate");

var yourDate = momentObj.format('L');
```